# Asynchronous API for Streaming Data from a Hardware Device

Tags: c#, api, dll, interface, asynchronous

I'm writing a library in C#, but I need to make it asynchronous. Normally you expose a set of DLL functions, and they take input parameters, and return a value when finished. But how can I make a library function (callable from C++/Delphi/Etc) that already starts streaming back output while still taking input?

The only solution I see now is to communicate using sockets/pipes/etc, instead of DLL calls.

Does someone have an example how to do this with normal DLL calls?

Comment: that really depends on what you are doing... you could even exchange pointers to functions which get called by your DLL when it needs the next chunk of input... you could use shared memory plus a global mutex to exchange data back and forth etc. To get a useful answer you really need to give much more detail...

Comment: There are various different options here - it partly depends what kind of output you've got, and what the input's like. When I hear "asynchronous" I tend to think of one-shot asynchronous calls, "Here's some input, give me some output when you're ready" but this sounds like you may want more of a streaming sort of solution. More context would be useful.

Comment: One option is having your functions take a callback parameter that you can call to process chunks of the output data. It might not be the most convenient of APIs though. A more natural way would be returning some sort of iterator object but that would make implementing your library more complicated, depending on where its input comes from.

Comment: It sounds more like you're looking for real-time and not async; if that's the case then yes you'll need to use sockets.

Comment: Have you solved the issue of calling .net library functions from native code?

Comment: So what is this program doing?

Comment: @Yahia It's a device driver, you can stream audio (line out), and it returns recorded audio out (line in). Shared memory/mutexes seems very complicated for end-users trying to use this driver.

Comment: @Joshua a device driver usually runs in kernel mode if I am not mistaken... and kernel mode drivers can't be written in C# AFAIK...

Comment: @JonSkeet It's indeed very similar to streaming, but the difference is that every input sample in the input stream will result in an output character in the output stream, so it's two-way streaming.

Comment: @Yahia It's not a 'real' device driver, its just a library for communicating with a piece of hardware I developed. Writing a kernel-level driver for it would be so much more work than just a simple DLL which accomplishes the same?

Comment: @Joshua does the input come from the hardware and the output goes to some application ?

Comment: @Yahia No, some application sends me audio, my hardware sends that audio digitally to an amplifier, and at the same time captures the output stream (microphone). The problem is that the sending application needs to adapt its outgoing audio to the microphone signal that is received. For example: they must be able to do FFT on the microphone data, and change the output audio according to the results, while still retaining gapless playback.

Comment: @Joshua Now that is some context... please update your question with this info... and check my answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments from the OP the calling application sends audio to the DLL, the DLL sends audio out via some USB interface, the DLL captures some audio from the mic interface and needs to send the captured audio back to the application while the application sends audio to the DLL etc.

Based on this and the fact that the calling can be written in rahter different languages I see some options for the communication channels:

- TCP/IP (depending on "desktop firewall settings" etc. this could be problematic!)
- Pipes
- COM objects with events/event handlers
- DLL with callback although this will be a bit hard to get working for all languages
- shared memory with global mutexes (could ease that for the consuming application by offering a "setup" function from the DLL which return the pointers and mutex names)

Answer (score 1):

One good model for a straightforward asynchronous library call (which is located in `System.dll`) is [WebClient.DownloadStringAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144202.aspx).  This method downloads from a `Uri` asynchronously, and raises the [DownloadStringCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringcompleted.aspx) event whenever it finishes.

Your library could likewise provide a `FooAsync` method, which doesn't block the current thread but raises a `FooDataReceived` event whenever some data comes into your library and a `FooCompleted` event whenever the calculation finishes.

Comment: that doesn't take into account that the OP wants both directions async - i.e. while giving some output back he wants to receive input async too...

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to go with this.  In most languages you can make async calls to methods using threads or dispatchers.  In general, as long as you make your dll [re-entrant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_%28subroutine%29) (capable of servicing multiple threads at the same time) the calling environment can take care of the async part.

It is possible to bake the async calls into your API, however.  An example of something that does this is the [WCF client proxies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730059.aspx?ppud=4).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a good article on this matter. If you just mover over the EndInvoke, it should work for you as well. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

- Since you want both Input and Output to be async, you will need a
  worker thread: If neither the inputting thread, nor the one taking
  the output can be blocked, both can't be bothered to do the work.
- Your already thought of communicating via pipes, but why use a pipe and not an internal strcuture?
- So you have this lock-free queue on the input, another one on the output and a worker thread
- The worker thread takes input from the inqueue, processes it, puts it into the outqueue
- If the input queue becomes empty, the worker thread has nothing to crunch on, so he raises a "need more data" event and then blocks on the input queue becoming (partly) full
- If the worker thread puts something in the output queue, he raises a "have more data" event, and if the output queue becomes (fully) full, he blocks on output space becoming available
- Your API is nonblocking: Neither sending input nor receiving output ever block
- Your API is async: Notifications (via Events) are given

Answer (score 0):

I like the following approach because it makes it really simple for the clients.

```
// your library
class Foo {
   public event EventHandler ComputeCompleted = (sender, e) => { };

   public void Compute() {
      // kick off work on a background thread
      // possibly using the BackgroundWorker object
      var bw = new BackgroundWorker();      
      bw.RunWorkerCompleted += RunWorkerCompleted;
      bw.RunWorkerAsync(); 
   }

   private void RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
        ComputeCompleted(this, new object()); 
   }
}

// calling code
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.ComputeCompleted += Completed;
foo.Compute();

private void Completed(object Sender, EventArgs e) {
   // process the result here
}
```

The gist is that you kick off a method in the library that returns right away, then notifies the caller via an event/delegate that the processing is complete.  You are then free to Invoke the execution back onto the UI thread as needed.

Obviously, error handling not included in the sample code.

Comment: and how would that work with/be usable from with C++, delphi etc. ?

Comment: @Yahia C++ has a managed mode which can easily consume C# constructs.  I haven't done anything with Delphi since 1995, so I couldn't really comment on that.

Comment: Yes but I understand from the OP that the library should usable from several languages including native ones (Delphi is native but can use COM for example)...

Comment: @Yahia In that case the library should be marked as `COM-visible` and the OP should run `regasm` tool against it to register it in the Registry.  The OP should then be able to access the event as a standard COM event.

Comment: I should also point out that the OP wants to `expose a set of DLL functions`, which .NET framework is not even capable of doing.  So I think this is as good as it will get as far as writing a library like that with .NET.